# How to iterate through Photos in a album using iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got the list of albums in Facebook using

```
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/albums" andDelegate:self];
```

I got the album id from the above request using objectForKey:@"id"

Now how do I get the list of photos in that album ? What is the request I should use for graph API ?

Answer (score 1):

The id of the album you got is the unique id to be used by the graphAPI. Using that, you can just treat it as if it were a person and then list the photos using

```
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"<your album id here>/photos" andDelegate:self];
```

for example, doing an albums call on the cocacola page

```
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"cocacola/albums" andDelegate:self];
```

shows me that the Wall Photos album's id is '99394368305'. Treating that like any other id, I can retrieve a list of the photos in it using

```
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"99394368305/photos" andDelegate:self];
```

and each photo comes with its complete data (likes, comments) and two links, one called photo and one called source which are links to the actual photos themselves that you can then use to download or display in your app

Comment: I tried it. didFailWithError prints null and didLoad doesn't get anything. Any idea what is going on ? I invoked it as [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"xxxxxxx/photos"
                                        andParams:Nil
                                        andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                        andDelegate:self];

Comment: Figured out what was wrong. I need not set the andParams and andHttpMethod. It works great. Thanks a lot.